# NormalBayesClassifier is giving undeclared identifier in opencv code

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

Im trying to use `NormalBayesClassifier` in my code to apply bag of words. The pre-training matrix is ready and given to the `trainme` matrix. I am using it as follows:

```
NormalBayesClassifier classifier;
classifier.train(trainme, labels);
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
error C2065: 'NormalBayesClassifier' : undeclared identifier
```

I have added all the correct libraries and all other opencv functions work, including the features2d functions.

Here are my libraries:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <cxcore.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

That should cover the `NormalBayesClassifier` function, then why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/normal_bayes_classifier.html), the class for the Normal Bayes Classifier is actually called `CvNormalBayesClassifier`.

The corresponding header file is:

```
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
```

Comment: Thank you, the library file helped fix the error. This was not mentioned in the documentation. Where did you get the info about the header file from? Thanks again

Comment: That is indeed not clearly described in the docs, but you can usually find the required header file in the URL: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/normal_bayes_classifier.html -> module "ml" means header file "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp".